# postgresql read json that contains character ' in a string

Tags: json, postgresql

Try to read this the json OV-fiets (http://fiets.openov.nl/locaties.json) in a postgres database with json_array_elements. Some names of train station contains the character `'` .
Example .....  `"description": "Helmond 't Hout"`

I believe that my script fails because of the ' between Helmond and the t.
The script i use:

```
WITH data AS (SELECT 'paste the json from http://fiets.openov.nl/locaties.json'::json AS fc)
SELECT
  row_number() OVER () AS gid,
     feat->'locaties'  AS locaties,
  FROM (
  SELECT json_array_elements(fc->'locaties') AS feat
  FROM data
) AS f;*
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

The error i get:

```
*syntax error at or near "Hout"
LINE 3: ...Images": [], "name": "HMH - OV-fiets - Helmond 't Hout", "ex.*
```

How can i change the script to avoid the syntax error due to the character '

Answer (score 0):

the easiest workaround here would probably be dollar quotes:

```
SELECT $dq$paste the json from http://fiets.openov.nl/locaties.json$dq$::json
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, single quotes need to be escaped by [doubling them](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS), e.g.:

```
select 'Arthur''s house';
```

As an alternative (in Postgres) you can use [dollar quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) to avoid changing the string:

```
SELECT $data$Arthur's house$data$
```